# What is the vim feature: --enable-pythoninterp

Tags: python, vim

I am going to build vim and see that it supports the `pythoninterp` feature by
`--enable-pythoninterp`. What is it? Since I am a big Python fan, I'd like to know more about it.

And also, what's the `--with-python-config-dir=PATH` for?

Answer (score 8):

vim supports scripting in various languages, Python being one of them. See `:h python` for more details.